# swift NSURL changes swift 3.1

Tags: mysql, json, swift, xcode, swiftcharts

I am currently attempting to retrieve data from mySQL with Swift in JSON format. I realize that `NSURL` has been changed to `URL`. I am following another older code to help guide me through this but it is out of date. I have errors (NSURL/URL) at `let request` and `let task`. I need some help sorting out how to do this correctly. Thank you!

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //********************************************************************
        //MySQL Url Request
        let URLRequest = NSURL(string: URLWarrick)
        //Creating mutable request
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URLRequest!)
        //setting method to post
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        //Task to send request

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
            data, response, error in

            //exiting if there is some error
            if error != nil{
                print("error is \(error)")
                return;
            }

            do {
                //converting response to NSDictionary
                var teamJSON: NSDictionary!
                WarrickJSON =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                //getting the JSON array teams from the response
                //let teams: NSArray = teamJSON["teams"] as! NSArray

                //looping through all the json objects in the array teams
                //for i in 0 ..< teams.count{

                    //getting the data at each index
                    //let teamId:Int = teams[i]["id"] as! Int!
                    //let teamName:String = teams[i]["name"] as! String!
                    //let teamMember:Int = teams[i]["member"] as! Int!

                    //displaying the data
                    //print("id -> ", teamId)
                    //print("name -> ", teamName)
                    //print("member -> ", teamMember)
                    //print("===================")
                    //print("")

                }
```

Comment: It is Swift convention to name your variables starting with a lowercase letter.  Another problem in your code is that `URLRequest` is a struct type in Swift3 so you can not use it as a name for your object.

Comment: I guess it is easy to see that I am a self taught beginner with Swift. I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical structure of a URL request. `GET` request is the default, so you don't need to have a `NSMutableURLRequest` to specify that.

```
if let url = URL(string: URLWarrick) {

    let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

        if let error = error {

            print(error.localizedDescription)

            return
        }

        if let data = data {

            if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) {

                if let dict = json as? Dictionary<String,Any> {

                    if let teams = dict["teams"] as? Array<Dictionary<String,Any>> {

                        for team in teams {

                            guard

                                let id = team["id"] as? Int,

                                let name = team["name"] as? String,

                                let member = team["memeber"] as? Int

                            else {

                                print("Error! - Data for this team is incomplete.")

                                continue
                            }

                            print(id, name, member)
                        }

                        return
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        print("Error! - Your data was invalid.")
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close to the correct format. To be correct in Swift 3 it should look something like the following:

```
if let let url = URL(string: URLWarrick) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    var session: URLSession = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
         // Your completion handler code goes here
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

The biggest change is that in swift 3 you no longer need a mutable url request it is handled correctly now as a var. And then you now use URLSession to send that request.

Comment: BTW you don't need a request for a simple GET you can just use the URL

Comment: you can also simplify that call `let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in // your code }`

Comment: I understand. Left as an example that the request was still mutable even though it was no longer called using NSMutableURLRequest.

Comment: @LeoDabus Just because it doesn't need to be a request, doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: Never said it is wrong. It is not needed. Why would you create a urlRequest object if the url is all you need to get the data?

Comment: I agree that it is not needed. But unfortunately the poster had it, and there may be additional need for modifying the headers that are unknown to us.